# How should I test Clam Anti-Virus?

Tags: email, email-server, anti-virus, clamav, postfix

I have setup a new email server and now I need to test that Clam Antivirus is scanning messages correctly.

How should I do this in a safe and controlled way?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The easiest way would be to us an [EICAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) test file. Create a text file and add in the following code:

`X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*`

More information [here](https://www.eicar.org/?page_id=3950)

Comment: More Info link (http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) is a *404*

Comment: `echo 'X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*' > clamav-testfile`

Answer (score 10):

download the [EICAR test file](https://www.eicar.org/download-anti-malware-testfile/) from [www.eicar.org](http://www.eicar.org) and scan it. it was made exactly for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

You could try to mail the test virus file see http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html